# Jquery preselect dropdown menu option in a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I asked here a couple of days ago how can i make a dropdown section in a form pre select an option.
I have got an answer and tried it and some other suggestions i have found online, all of which had failed.
I attached two pictures showing what I did, so hopefully you guys will be able to help me.

(bear in mind that i used a plugin which only allows me to add code not edit the given one)

Num1
[thats how the plugin made the form, i cannot edit it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OmJy.jpg)

Num2
[thats what i have tried and it did not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD4JZ.jpg)

EDIT

here is the code the pulgin made:

```
<label class="fitText" style="font-size: 16px;">Product</label>
<select name="Product" data-export-field="">

          <option value=""> - Product - </option>


          <option value="A" data-price="0">
            A

          </option>

          <option value="B" data-price="14">
            B

            (+$14.00)

          </option>

      </select>
```

What I made:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#Product option[value=A]').attr('selected','selected');
});
</script>
```

Hope you guys will help me! :D

Thanks
Yarin

Comment: Is there any way you can copy and paste the code into your question? Debugging code from an image seems... inefficient.

Comment: Done, you are right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what you want-

script -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=Product] > option[value=A]').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

The `#` selector is for ID's, not name. Use the same selector for name as value.

`$(document).ready()` (or `$(function() {} )`) should be a little bit quicker as it calls when the DOM is ready for manipulation rather than when everything is ready. I've also heard that `$(window).load(function() {})` can be called at unintentional times, project depending.

Otherwise your code is solid.

Comment: Or you can try this one :

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but the code does not seem to work. maybe because the code i add is located in the body? and i have found this piece of code:<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{=htmlSafe(m.itemName || 'Product')}}"> does it have anything to do with what i am trying to achieve?

Comment: Shouldn't. That's just the form submission. If you add the line `console.log($('select[name=Product] > option[value=A]'))` right below the docReady line does it output the object to your console?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this one :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#select_id").val('A');

});
```

On page load, set default value for the select tag. Might help you.